# Nodejs ssh convert output byte stream to a sliceable string

Tags: node.js, ssh, npm

i am using npm ssh2 module to do `'ls -l'` on remote machine & read the data... 
in my connection.exec callback (which gets called when a command runs & send the data back), i am getting a data output which looks like an array of bytes. In the place of line feed, i am getting 10 as the byte value..

o/p stream looks like,

```
Object[97, 10, 98, 10, 99, 10]
```

which is the ascii form of 
a
b
c

now, the confusion is how to convert them into strings & slice them with line feed character

what i did::::

```
var fsArr = JSON.stringify(data).slice(String.fromCharCode(10))
fsArr.forEach(......)
```

this failed with the error,

```
Object[97, 10, 98, 10, 99, 10] has no method 'forEach'
```

Why doesn't JSON.stringify convert the data byte stream into a valid string? & if slice method is not returning an array, what else can it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `Buffer` object and you want a `String`.  It's usually enough to do this:

```
var s = String(data)
var fsArr = JSON.stringify(s).slice(String.fromCharCode(10))
fsArr.forEach(......)
```

EDIT:
Someone kindly pointed out that 'slice' is not what you want here, either.  You probably want to split the string on newlines, using `s.split('\n')` or a similar expression.

In any case, to get the Buffer data into a String, you just have to call `String()` on it.